# Open command-line-mode from VimScript function

Tags: command-line, functions, map-operator, command

How to reproduce this mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :DoSomething <C-r>=do_something_arguments()<CR>
```

..in a function?

The desired effect is to open command-line mode with some text filled in, and leave it at that.

`:normal` only works on "complete commands", same seems to be also true for `:exec`.

Reasoning behind this is to define an operator (using [vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user)) that would prepopulate a command:

```
call operator#user#define('conf-entry', 'Op_command_conf_entry')
function! Op_command_conf_entry(motion_wiseness)
  normal! `[yv`]

  let l:conf_path = '~/.vim/conf/_' . @" . '/'

  exec ':EditCreating ' . l:conf_path
endfunction

nmap _c  <Plug>(operator-conf-entry)
```

Here, the `exec` line executes immediately, which is the behavior I want to change.

What I'm probably looking for is the command-line-mode equivalent to `:startinsert`, something like `:startcommand`.

The alternative solution is to use `input()` which can offer both prepopulating as well as enabling completion. However this is not exactly command-line-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of `:h map-<expr>`. That is

```
"instead of exec
return ':EditCreating ' . l:conf_path
```

And

```
nnoremap <expr><Plug>(operator-conf-entry) ... whatever
```

Probably, you'll need some more fixes in your code, but it's impossible to say without seeing the whole picture.

Otherwise, there's no such thing as `startcommand`, so only `feedkeys` or `input` remain.

Comment: Unfortunately, `<expr>` seems incompatible with vim-operator-user's <Plug> mappings, however `feedkeys` produced exactly the result I was looking for.

Comment: @mwgkgk Using `feedkeys()` should be avoided whenever possible. In your case, you should probably `call()` your operator function manually and return the result as `<expr>`, instead of `execute`-ing `g@`.